# Replace some values of csv column for values in another

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've csv that looks like this (without the spaces between the columns):

```
id, process_id, name,                                   application_label
2,  384,        com.qualcomm.telephony,                 com.qualcomm.atfwd
6,  0,          com.facebook.katana:videoplayer,        \N
7,  0,          com.facebook.orca:videoplayer,          \N
9,  29195,      com.wsandroid.suite,                    McAfee Security
10, 12909,      com.life360.android.safetymapd:service, \N
```

**How to, and Which is the fastest way to replace the '\N' on application_label columns for the values in the name column?**

The output should be:

```
id, process_id, name,                                   application_label
2,  384,        com.qualcomm.telephony,                 com.qualcomm.atfwd
6,  0,          com.facebook.katana:videoplayer,        com.facebook.katana:videoplayer
7,  0,          com.facebook.orca:videoplayer,          com.facebook.orca:videoplayer
9,  29195,      com.wsandroid.suite,                    McAfee Security
10, 12909,      com.life360.android.safetymapd:service, com.life360.android.safetymapd:service
```

**Curiosity**:

If it was a pandas dataframe what's the fastest way to do this?
i've make something like this:

```
for index in df.index:
    if df.get_value(index, 'application_label') == r'\N':
        df.set_value(index, 'application_label', df.get_value(index, 'name'))
```

But can i do this even faster?

Comment: Have a look at `replace`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: yes but i can't figure out which value to give to the 'value' param, i see that value=1 replace all my '\N' to 1 but i want dynamic values compared to the other column

Comment: If you need raw speed on CPython, Pandas is the way to go. `pandas.read_csv()` is really well optimized. Then get rid of the for loop and follow @chthonicdaemon's example. Finally, write the dataframe back using `to_csv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
mask = DF['application_label'] == r'\N'
DF.loc[mask, 'application_label'] = DF['name']
```

Comment: I think you need == for the mask

Comment: @Orenshi- updated to the answer. Thanx for your comments 

Comment: clever and way fast then my loop.

Comment: and if i want to change values directly on the csv?

Comment: If the above answer useful to you, please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: @RubenAlves, note that it's not possible to modify the CSV file in place, since the replacement values take more space than the original `\N` values. You'll have to either read all data into memory and overwrite the original file, or write to a temporary file while reading the original.

Comment: ok there is no inplace on csv :(, i'll use pandas with this great optimization to my for loop